# Unable to add domain name firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I have purchased the domain name as `domain-name.in.net` from bigrock. But adding custom domain name in firebase, it only considering in.net and not considering domain-name.
Any solutions guys?
Due to above issue i am unable to verify ownership in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

In the hosting section of the Firebase console, enter in the custom domain name of "domain-name.in.net". In your hosting provider add the A record with the IP address. Wait up to 24 hours for the record to propagate.

The subdomain should now correctly go to your Firebase app. Note, if you're concerned about the console saying "needs setup", ignore. It always says that and seems to be a bug with Firebase.